# bash script to perform operation on each argument against the final argument

Tags: bash, arguments, shift

Suppose you want to make a `bash` script which supports no options but acts like `cp`, because the `cp` supplied by your system does not accept multiple sources.

The usage for the system's (hypothetical and broken) `cp` is:

```
cp source target    # target may be a directory
```

The usage for the script will be:

```
cp.sh source... target    # target must be a directory
```

Here's a starting point for the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tgt="$1"
shift
for src in "$@"; do
    echo cp $src $tgt
done
```

When run with the arguments "`a b c d`" (note that `d` is the target), it outputs:

```
cp b a
cp c a
cp d a
```

The goal is to fix the script to output this instead, while keeping the code simple:

```
cp a d
cp b d
cp c d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/test.bash source1 source2 target1

```
#!/bin/bash

target=${!#} 

if [ ! -d $target ] ; then
    echo "$target must be a directory " >&2
    exit 1;
fi

args=("$@")
unset args[${#args[@]}-1]

for src in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo cp $src $target
done
```

will output

```
cp source1 target1
cp source2 target1
```

Comment: I really like this one!  I'm adding quotes around the uses of $target and $src (to support paths with spaces), but otherwise this is pretty much perfect.

Comment: You should add an `if [ -f "$src" ]` (or `-a`) inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array slicing to leave off the last of the arguments:

```
tgt="${!#}"
for src in "${@:1:$#-1}"; do
    cp "$src" "$tgt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Why? The cp command already does that. Do a **man cp** and you will see.

If you still insist, here are two ways to get the last argument. Method 1: place command line in an array and extract the last element:

```
arg=("$@")
last_arg=${arg[(($# - 1))]}
```

The first line puts the command line arguments into the array arg. If your command line contains **a b c d** then arg[0] == 'a', ... argv[3] == 'd'.

The second line extract the last argument. The (($# - 1)) takes the number of arguments (4 in this case), subtract 1 from it (to get 3). That expression then becomes:

```
last_arg=${arg[3]}
```

which points to the last argument.

---

The second method is not very portable, it makes use of the BASH_ARGV variable, which is $@ but in reverse order. If your command line is **a b c d** then ${BASH_ARGV[0]} == 'd', ... ${BASH_ARGV[3]} == 'a':

```
last_arg=${BASH_ARGV[0]}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Of course "cp" already supports this behavior.  I have another program to run which doesn't, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
tgt="${@: -1}"    # get the last parameter
for src in "$@"; do
    if [[ $src != $tgt ]]; then
        echo cp "$src" "$tgt"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Not bad, but I prefer the "unset" method for removing the last argument over the comparison used here (imagine what happens if the source actually does equal the target with this code).

Comment: But you wouldn't want to hear this, would you? "cp: `d' and `d' are the same file"

Comment: Or "cp: omitting directory `d'"

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
t=(x "$@")
i=1; while [ $i -lt $# ]; do
  echo cp ${t[$i]} ${t[$#]}
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Comment: Do not use `$*`; it does not preserve spaces within arguments (it generates extra arguments).  Use `"$@"` - almost always.

Comment: Quite true, I always use "$@" when chaining a command, not sure why I didn't do it here...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any bash-specific features:

```
eval last=\${$#}
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
  echo "cp $1 $last"
  shift
done
```

Comment: That relies on $300 working as the 300th argument (when there are 300 arguments). It doesn't work in all Bourne shells (e.g. Solaris 10 /bin/sh: `set -- a b c d e f g h i j k l; echo $10` generates 'a0' and not 'j'.

Comment: Ditto for Korn shell (again, on Solaris 10).

Comment: Of course, for $# > 9 you need to use ${N} (e.g. ${10}, ${300}). That works fine for me on Solaris 10, using ksh, bash, /bin/sh.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly without writing a script using **xargs**:

```
echo source1 source2 | tr "\n" "\0" | tr " " "\0" | 
   xargs --verbose -0 -I{} cp {} dest
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to extract the last parameter:

eval tgt=\$$#

then just process the same way you are and when you hit $# just exit the loop

Here's the whjole script:

```
eval tgt=\$$#

for src in $@
do
 if [ "$src" == "$tgt" ];
 then
    exit
fi
echo cp $src $tgt
done
```

Pretty simple if you ask me!

Comment: This method beats mine hand down. Hat off to you.

Comment: The part about stopping when $# is hit requires tracking the loop index in addition, which I don't much care for.  And `eval` isn't necessary, as some of the other answers show.

Comment: you dont need an index, just compare the current value to tgt.  What I meant by exiting when you hit $# means when you hit the value of $#